# Can I break Lihzahrd Brick with any other pickaxe than Picksaw?

Tags: terraria

I'm playing on easy mode and I just found the Lihzahrd area.

Are there any pickaxe I can craft to enter that area?

Do I need to keep search for those Golems so I can get the Picksaw?

Comment: Have you beaten Plantera yet?

Comment: Not yet... actually, I couldn't find any boss. I'm probably looking in the wrong places. The area becomes available after killing Plantera?

Comment: Several things in Terraria are based on defeating bosses. Defeating Plantera allows access to the Jungle Temple (Lizahrd Area). But there are several bosses you need to beat to access Plantera.

Comment: So, what would be a better approach? Should I keep digging deeper instead of wider in order to find bosses?

Comment: @vianna77 Are you in hardmode or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only pickaxes that can break [Lihzard Brick](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Brick) are the picksaw, the [laser drill](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Laser_Drill), and the [luminite pickaxes.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Luminite_Pickaxes) All of them require that you have defeated the Golem to acquire. The Golem is the boss found inside the lihzard Temple.

[Plantera](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera) always drops the [Temple key](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Temple_Key) which opens the door to the Lihzard temple. Plantera's bulb (an object that you destroy to summon Plantera) begins to appear after you have defeated all three mechanical bosses. It shows up pink on the map.

The entrance to the temple is usually found along one of its top slopes. usually fairly near to the top. Whether it is on the right or the left is random.

Hopefully that is of some use.

Comment: Thanks! I guess there is a long path before entering the Lihzard Temple. The thing is I couldn't find any of those mechanical bosses.

Comment: @vianna77 Are you in hardmode already? Because that lihzard temple is end game content. OOr close to end game anyway.

Comment: No... I started to play like 3 days ago. To be fair, I have been playing A LOT! The thing is, I can't find those mechanical bosses (or any other boss). Are their location random? Or they are always very deep?
When is a good moment to switch from Easy to Hardmode?

Comment: @vianna77 the mechanical bosses have a chance of spawning each night similar to the bosses before that. However if you wait for them to spawn normally you're gonna be waiting a long time to defeat all the bosses. It's easier to just craft the summoning item for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no pickaxe you can craft in order to get into the temple without defeating Plantera.

The Rod of Discord used to be able to be used to get in but has since been patched

However you can still enter the Jungle Temple by using the Teleporters on either side of the door.

Also you can use a Teleporter just in front of the door and then activate the other one while standing on the edge so that you materialize partway inside the door.

The other ways to get in utilize hammered blocks. Create a path leading up to the Jungle Temple door with a 2 high gap, so your head will hit the blocks you've placed. Now walk towards the door while hammering the blocks into the angle shape and you will be able to enter the Temple. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGcGywYriXI) for a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks! I just started to figure out how to defeat bosses... at some point I will find Plantera... I just killed the Eye of Cuthulhu. Is it possible to kill all the bosses in Normal mode?

Comment: @vianna77 if by Normal mode you mean pre-hardmode, then no. You must defeat the 3 mechanical bosses, which only appear in hardmode, for Plantera bulbs to start spawning. Also the mechanical bosses are magnitudes more difficult than the previous bosses such as Eye of Cthulhu and Plantera much stronger than the mechanical bosses. So if you're only just now defeating the first set of bosses it's unlikely you'll have the equipment to beat plantera.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, pre-hardmode. So, I have to defeat a few other bosses in order to get to hard mode, right? Nice. So, should I just keep digging and looking around until I find the items to summon them?

Comment: @vianna77 to get into hard mode you need to defeat the wall of flesh, summoned by dropping a voodoo guide doll (dropped by voodoo demons) into lava. The pre hardmode bosses are great for their drops which includes material to make weapons and armor/tools. Also you may want to check the recipes for those summoning items, as the materials are quite common and I have no doubts that you already have acquired them.

Comment: Thanks, I will start to dig further... I imagine the demons and lava are deeper than where my character is right now.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the mechanic you can walk through jungle temple by placing actuators on the door and linking a switch to them. Turn on the switch and walk through. Looks like it is still closed but not.